# Bootstrap nav-item positioning outside justify-content-center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm struggling to position button which is nav container to the right side of the screen. All other nav-items need to be on the center so i`m using justify content center.

I have tried to use:

- margin-left:auto on the button, but it moves other links on the left side.
- remove justify-content-center on nav and add flex-shrink:1 with margin-left: auto on the button.
- move button outside nav flex group, but then button appears on the next row.

Screenshot of the nav container and button what need to position on the right side:

[image: Screenshot of the nav container and button what need to position on the right side]

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Places</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost on the right track.

You would need to take the button out of the list, and then declare the entire enclosing nav for the list and button to be a flex with center. That would more or less result in the same thing you have now, but it will have the list and the button as separate items. Then you'd take the list and make it grow as much as it can to the end using the class `flex-grow-1` or `flex-fill`. That will push the button to the extreme right still being on the same row.

Here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbuanv5t/)

Comment: (Good advice about supplying  JS Fiddle, but this does not age well in answers - answers are for a wide audience and not just the question author. It is best to add this to a comment under the question instead).